# Are the values 161137531201111100, 1.611375312011111e+17 equal?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to manipulate a dataframe. The value of in a list which I use to append a column to the dataframe is 161137531201111100. However, I created a dictionary whose keys are the unique values of this column, and I use this dictionary in further operations. This could used to run perfectly before.

However, after trying this code on another data I had the following error:

```
KeyError: 1.611375312011111e+17
```

which means that this value is not the of the dictionary; I tried to trace the code, everything seemed to be okay. However, when I opened the csv file of the dataframe I built I found out that the value that is causing the problem is:  161137531201111000 which is not in the list(and ofc not a key in the dictionary) I used to create this column of dataframe. This seems weird. However, I don't know what is the reason? Is there any reason that a number is saved in another way?

And how can I save it as it is in all phases? Also, why did it change in the csv?

Comment: They are equal, yes.

Comment: @tkausl in Python, no, they are not. `print(1.611375312011111e+17 == 161137531201111000)` shows "False".

Comment: Numbers with `.` are floats and inexact. Therefore comparing floats with other numbers may fail. Without `.` they are integers and exact (but can overflow under some conditions).

Comment: Since you want to use numbers as dict keys, I think the point here is to use dtype `int` consistently. If you bring `float` into the game somewhere, you could fall into the pitfalls of floating point arithmetic (comparison for equality...).

Answer (score 2):

No unfortunately, they are not equal

```py
print(1.611375312011111e+17 == 161137531201111000)` # False.
```

The problem lies in the way floating numbers are handled by computers, in general, and most programming languages, including Python.

Always use integers (and *not* "too large") when doing computations if you want exact results.

See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for generic explanation that you definitely must know as a programmer, even if it's not specific to Python.

(and be aware that Python tries to do a rather good job at keeping precision on **integers**, that unfortunately won't work on floating-point numbers).

And just for the sake of "fun" with floating point numbers, `1.611375312011111e+17` is actually equal to the integer `161137531201111104`!

```py
print(format (1.611375312011111e+17, ".60g"))      # shows 161137531201111104
print(1.611375312011111e+17 == 161137531201111104) # True

a = dict()
a[1.611375312011111e+17] = "hello"
#print(a[161137531201111100])       # Key error, as in question
print(a[161137531201111104])        # This one shows "hello" properly!
```

Comment: different types *should not* compare equal, no? I mean, without taking into account their numerical value in this case. If *both* were of type float here, it would be the comparison for equality problem - if used as dict keys.

Comment: @MrFuppes Comparison on numbers is done numerically in Python. I mean, the type is not compared as a strict requirement. For instance, `print(1.0 == 1)` prints "True". And it works for dict : `a = dict()` `a[1] = "hello"` `print(a[1.0])` : that properly prints "Hello". So, no, the problem is not the type, it's really that `1.611375312011111e+17` does not equal the integer number `161137531201111000`, du to the floating point numebrs' inherent imprecision.

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification - that seems like too much convenience to me ^^ wasn't aware of that (anymore), got more into strictly typed languages lately

Comment: Yes, that is indeed potentially confusing. Python is less tedious, especially to learn programming, and is thus very popular... but when you scrap a bit too much you need to be aware of details. Thanks for the comment anyway, I also had a doubt and had to check this as well :P